install micro-ROS on Windows?
I am trying to install micro-ROS on Win10, do you know if it's possible? If yes, can you link me a tutorial? I suspect it might not be possible.

This has been asked before, Micro ROS on Windows, but the question (and answers) doesn't seem to have survived the migration, unfortunately.
To quote the best looking answer:

... we've setup a micro-ROS build / development environment on Windows. This also targets a non-Windows target.
Summarising: if you have a toolchain which you can tell CMake about, building micro-ROS is basically like any other CMake project which you cross-compile. Make sure to invoke colcon with --cmake-args [..] -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=C:\path\to\your\toolchain_file.cmake.
Nothing else is needed, except a Python 3 venv which contains the required Colcon python packages. The list of those can be found in the "Setting up a Windows development environment for ROS 2". Note: as you already have a toolchain, you do not need MSVC, or any of the related tools. You do need: Python 3, CMake, Git and I would recommend using Ninja.
At this point you should be able to build a simple "ROS 2 package" with Colcon and your toolchain. Building micro-ROS now comes down to which version of micro-ROS and which packages to include.
...
If you can't drive your compiler/build using CMake, things get a little more complex

There are other comments and answers on that same page, that are also helpful, so please refer to the link above.
There is also this question, Micro-ros static library in windows, but no answers.

If the migration question and answer can be undeleted, then this question is probably a duplicate of that.
